# How to get result for a condition in a single line in r

Tags: r, if-statement, testing, filter

I have a piece of code where I have to filter a dataframe based on a value. I read a dataset with 100 rows of data.

```
baseData = fread(file = "./Data/ABC.csv", data.table = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, showProgress = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

After I filter,

```
baseData = baseData %>% filter(., ab == 10)
```

Now I want to check whether the data has been filtered correctly. So I have written a condition,

```
ifelse((baseData$ab == 10),
       "ab has been filtered correctly",
       "ERROR")
```

but I have received the output like this,

```
[1] "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly"
[4] "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly"
[7] "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly"
[10] "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly" "ab has been filtered correctly"
.
.
.
```

I need a output like this,

```
"ab has been filtered correctly"
```

If possible along with the count of how many errors?

Answer (score 2):

The all function would help, you can use it to make your conditional operator.

```
if(all(baseData[,"ab"] == 10)){
  print("success")
}else{
  print("fail")
}
```